Saving a character to an int variable using scanf( ) making unexpected char equivalent int value
I was checking library function isupper() to check if the function version or macro version of
isupper() is efficient depending on storage used or runtime and I have this peculiar problem
when using scanf() for storing input character to a int varibale.
Here is my code-
#include<stdio.h>

int my_isupper(int );

int main() {
    int c;

    printf("Enter a alphabet to check if it is upper case or not\n");
    
    //c = getchar(); // getchar(), getc() works fine though
        
    scanf("%c", &c);

    /*
    Doesn't work when c is a int but not initialized to 0
    Works fine on some machine no matter c is a char, int or not initialized to 0
    Is it compiler/machine dependent? if so, which part ( scanf()?) has dependency?
    */

    printf("test1: %d\n", c);

    if(my_isupper(c))
        printf("%c is upper case\n", c);

    else
        printf("%c is not upper case\n", c);

    return 0;
}

int my_isupper(int c) {

    printf("test2: %c\n", c);

    int value = (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')? 1 : 0;

    printf("test3: %d\n", value);

    return value;
}

when the variable c is set as char it works fine. when it is set as int the program works fine
with getchar(), getc() etc library functions but when using scanf(), if the variable is set as
int and not initialized to 0 then scanf() is storing 32577 for the char 'A' , 32578 for the
char 'B' and so on.
When giving input: A , return value should be 1, but the return value I am getting is 0 as the
condition is not satisfied because scanf() is saving 32577 for the char A, and 32778 for char B
and so on.

The scanf format %c expects a char *. Mismatching format and argument type leads to undefined behavior.

Always a bug: not checking the return value from scanf.

Try enabling compiler warnings.  I think most compilers will warn about passing the wrong pointer types to scanf.

Also relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165598/difference-between-letter-and-alphabet-in-english

You are lying to scanf with scanf("%c", &c); saying c is a char while it is actually an int. This is an undefined behavior bug so anything can happen.
One likely outcome (not guaranteed but likely) is that a byte is read into the lowest address of the int. In case of a little endian machine, then it will work just fine because it expects a number 0 to 255 in that byte to directly correspond with values 0 to 255. So the result of the int will end up as that value given that all other bytes of the int are zero. Or alternatively on a big endian machine, you would be writing to the most significant byte resulting in a very large number.
However, you never initialized c so those other bytes may contain garbage values. Or possibly zeroes if you are unlucky - many debug builds zero out local variables that aren't initialized, which is by no means any guarantee from C. Printing the contents of a local variable which does not have it's address taken is also undefined behavior. Ok so you did take the address during the scanf call. But assuming a mainstream system with no trap representations for int, it is still unspecified behavior - meaning any combination may happen and you may get any value, but at least the program won't crash and burn unexpectedly as with undefined behavior.

Note that all of the current generation of optimizing C compilers take J.2 bullet point "[the behavior is undefined if] the value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate" as normative and as-if the crossed-out words were not present, despite this not being supported by the actual normative text of the standard, which means printing the contents of an uninitialized variable of any kind is UB regardless of whether its address has been taken.

@zwol Yep, annex J is broken and the committee is aware of the "wobbly values" situation, which still has not settled in C23 afaik. For example I recall asking this questions from where we could conclude that clang's ambition is to become an implementation for the famous "ISO compatible Death Station 9000" - it abruptly stopped code generation halfways through the C source just because it encountered an indeterminate value.

@zwol ...at which point it doesn't really matter what the C standards says, if the ambition of the compiler maintainers is to produce a useless but potentially ISO compliant product, for the purpose of keeping compiler maintainers' egos happy. An not with the ambition to produce a quality piece of open source software for the benefit of mankind, which goes at lengths at staying true to the programmer's intentions over anything else.

@Lundin I used to work with these people and I'm quite certain that as far as they are concerned, to the extent the actual normative text does not support their preferred semantics for indeterminate values, it is the standard that is defective. And in this specific case I agree with them: there's never a good reason to want to read an indeterminate value, and it does improve optimization of real code to assume it never happens. (Contrast, say, clang's very surprising treatment of intentional infinite loops.)

@zwol I program very low-level stuff and there are reasons. For example you might want to set up a RAM segment which is preserved from the previous execution directly after a watchdog reset. You will have code which checks if the reset reason was power on = initialize that RAM area, or if it was another reset reason = don't touch it but read it.

@zwol But such special cases aside, if I happen to write a bug that reads an indeterminate value by accident, I would appreciate if all that happens is that my program prints some garbage. Instead of violently crashing and becoming a useless PoS. The user of my program agrees. Suppose the part which read the indeterminate value wasn't important at all, but the rest of the program is very important - the parts which clang arrogantly refused to even generate - they aren't even present in my executable. Just because I had a little bug in some background logging feature or whatever.
